# How to perform if let binding with struct in swift

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I now the output produce by this piece of code but my problem is that how could I perform if let binding on struct in swift.

Is if let binding is not possible with struct in swift. if yes that how could we do that

```
struct Account {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct AccountViewModel {
    private var account: Account

    var accountName: String {
        return "Account Name >>>>> " + self.account.name
    }

    init(acc: Account) {
        self.account = acc
    }

    mutating func updateAccountName(name: String) {
        self.account.name = name
    }
}

let acc = Account.init(name: "First Account")
print("Account Name >>>>>", acc.name)

var accountVM: AccountViewModel?
accountVM = AccountViewModel.init(acc: acc)

if var accVM = accountVM {
    accVM.updateAccountName(name: "Update Name")
}

print(accountVM?.accountName ?? "")
```

Comment: `if let` makes a constant and a constant struct cannot call `mutating` method on it.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan so how could we update the value for that. I don't want to use the ! unwrapping

Comment: You can use `if lat` for optional

Comment: @Ajay This comes down to making a choice between value type vs reference type. Struct is value type and it makes another copy when assigned to another container. IMHO, a ViewModel doesn't make a good candidate for a struct.

Answer (score 3):

`struct`s are *value types,* therefore in

```
if var accVM = accountVM {
    accVM.updateAccountName(name: "Update Name")
}
```

`accVm` is a (mutable) *copy* of `accountVM!`. Therefore
you can modify `accVM`, but that does not change `accountVM`. If your intention is to
update `accountVM` then you can assign it from the mutated `accVM`:

```
if var accVM = accountVM {
    accVM.updateAccountName(name: "Update Name")
    accountVM = accVM
}
```

Alternatively, use optional chaining instead of optional binding:

```
accountVM?.updateAccountName(name: "Update Name")
```

Comment: You are suggesting to resign value to the old data after every update to the current value or use to optional chaining to update and retrieve  data. So we can't use optional binding with struct.

Comment: @AjaySinghMehra: You can use optional binding with structs, but you cannot use it to modify the original value.

Comment: That indicate that you can't write a safe and clean code while using struct in swift.

Comment: @AjaySinghMehra maybe not _clean_ in the sense that your linter appreciates the code, but you definitely can write it in a _safe_ way. Keep in mind that you are dealing with value types, so multi-threaded access is not an issue. When you can assert that the value is there (e.g. by `if foo != nil`) then it's 100% safe to access it (both `foo!.bar` and `foo?.bar` will work).

Answer (score 1):

Of course Swift gives us a lot of syntactic sugar and optional binding is the recommended way for unwrapping optionals. But in my opinion, it's a normal situation when we compare a variable with `nil` by traditional 'old school' way.

So, you could replace

```
if var accVM = accountVM { 
    ccVM.updateAccountName(name: "Update Name") 
}
```

by

```
if accountVM != nil { 
    accountVM!.updateAccountName(name: "Update Name") 
}
```

Comment: I don't want to user ! or ?, as if you use swift lint that will through an error

Comment: But why? Do you have a serious reason?

Comment: I am using swift lint and it will consider ! as error

Comment: Ok. We also use lint, but by default `force_unwrapping` rule is disabled in lint, so we don't have such problems like yours.